# How can I change the folder of a plugin in Django CMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

I've created a new plugin using:

```
//create a new plugin
> ./manage.py startapp hero
```

And added it to the settings.py

It created a structure to which I've added files:

```
- hero
   - static
     hero.css
   - templates
     hero.html
   __init__.py
   cms_plugins.py
   models.py
```

I want to put all the plugins in a new directory:

```
  - plugins
    - hero
    - other plugin
```

How can I change a plugin's folder in Django CMS?

Comment: Hi there!  Take a look in https://www.paulpepper.com/blog/2014/02/locating-django-applications-their-own-sub-directory/

Comment: If your other plugin's aren't related to the hero app, then they'd surely live in apps of their own? Each app having a `cms_plugins.py` or a `cms_toolbars.py` etc is common practice. To have the `hero` app plugins in an app called `plugins` would be a little disjointed & make the `hero` app difficult to install in to other CMS projects.

Comment: @Tico worked! want to post this as an answer?